# How to apply a function to certain columns for multiple times in R?

Tags: r

everybody. I've come across a problem in my R project. I got a dataset of crime rates in the US. It looks like this:
state   year    population crimes (there is 20 more columns)
Alabama 2000    4447100 4059.7
Alabama 2001    4468912 3876.8
Alabama 2002    4478896 4027.8
Alabama 2003    4503726 4046.4
Alabama 2004    4525375 4029.3
Alabama 2005    4548327 3900.0
Alabama 2006    4599030 3941.0
Alabama 2007    4627851 3977.7
Alabama 2008    4661900 4084.5
Alabama 2009    4708708 3780.4
Alabama 2010    4785401 3528.0
Alabama 2011    4803689 3605.4
Alabama 2012    4822023 3502.2
Alabama 2013    4833722 285.2
Alabama 2014    4849377 283.4
Alabama 2015    4858979 328.3
Alabama 2016    4863300 2947.8
Alabama 2017    4874747 2957.3
Alabama 2018    4887871 2817.2
Alabama 2019    4903185 2674.4
Alaska  2000    626932  3682.5
Alaska  2001    633630  3655.1
Alaska  2002    641482  3759.7
Alaska  2003    648280  3761.6
Alaska  2004    657755  3370.9
Alaska  2005    663253  3615.0
Alaska  2006    670053  3578.1
Alaska  2007    683478  3379.2
Alaska  2008    686293  2927.3
Alaska  2009    698473  2940.4
...[this is the dataset](https://corgis-edu.github.io/corgis/csv/state_crime/)

So long story short, I have 50 states listed from A-Z, and year is 2000-2019. For example, I want to use apply function to calculate the mean of the "crimes" from 2000 to 2019 for all 50 states. So what I would like to get is 50 means. For example the mean for Alabama would be (4059.7+...+2674.4)/20

please, how can I possibly get the result I want with least efforts?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd use `dplyr`, specifically the `group_by()` to group by state and `summarise()` to calculate the mean crimes for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @Paul Stafford Allen comment.

Assuming your data is in a data.frame or `tibble` called "df"

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(state) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(crimes))
```

Incidentally, if you want mean crimes by state and year, it's a simple change:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(state, year) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(crimes))
```